# Dim c as MyClass & Dim c as New MyClass

Tags: vb.net, oop

It's a simple concept, but one I've never been taught. Can someone please explain the differences between the following 2 statements please:

```
Dim c as MyClass

Dim c as New MyClass
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Dim c as New MyClass` is a shortcut and strictly equivalent to the following:

```
Dim c as MyClass = New MyClass
```

Both are different to `Dim c as MyClass`: the statement without `New` only declares the variable, it doesn’t assign a value. This means that the variable has a default value of `Nothing`.

`New MyClass`, on the other hand, assigns a newly-created *instance* of that class to the variable.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, thats explained it very simply to me!